# Linkwise Affiliate integration in Woocommerce thankyou page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, google-tag-manager

I have a Woocommerce store and I like to send an order completion data to an affiliate and they ask me to include the following code:

```
<script>
lw("setCurrency", "numeric currency code, e.g. 978 for Euro");
lw("addItem", {
    id: "ID (as given in the XML) of first product in order"
    ,price: "unit price of first product, without VAT e.g. 13,49"
    ,quantity: "quantity of first product"
    ,payout: "1"
});
lw("addItem", {
    id: "ID (as given in the XML) of second product in order"
    ,price: "unit price of second product, without VAT e.g. 25,16"
    ,quantity: "quantity of second product"
    ,payout: "1"
});
// more items
lw("setCoupon", "0");
lw("thankyou", {
    orderid: "unique order ID"
    ,status: "pending"
});
</script>
<noscript>
<img
src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/acl.php?program=program_ID&amp;decimal
=,_or_.&amp;itemid[1]=ID_of_first_product&amp;itemprice[1]=unit_pri
ce_of_first_product&amp;itemquantity[1]=quantity_of_first_product&a
mp;itempayout[1]=1&amp;itemid[2]=ID_of_second_product&amp;itemprice
[2]=unit_price_of_second_product&amp;itemquantity[2]=quantity_of_se
cond_product&amp;itempayout[2]=1&amp;coupon_price=0&amp;status=pend
ing&amp;orderid=unique_order_ID" style="width:0px;height:0px;"/>
</noscript>
```

In my thank you page - Checkout Page.

I have read that this is related to the WooCommerce Data Layer, I have searched for many hours not found anything to help me.

Thank you in advance.

Adding additional info

I use the Header and Footer plug in of WordPress and put the following code:

```
<!-- LinkWise Script -->
<script async src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/tl.js"></script>
<script>
window.lw=window.lw||function(){(lw.q=lw.q||[]).push(arguments)};lw
.l=+new Date;
lw("setProgram", "12686");
lw("setDecimal", ",");
</script>

<!-- End LinkWise Script -->
```

on every page of the website on header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to integrate it; But you will have to add some settings to the code:

- The program number (your program affiliation ID)
- The decimal separator (can be a coma or a point).
- The currency number code (in ISO_4217 format).

> You will have to **remove other related code** from header or footer as not needed anymore…

The code is divided in 2 parts:

- The utility function that contain Linkwise Affiliate script (and settings)
- The hooked function that will run Linkwise Affiliate scripts on order received (2 choices):

The first function *(Where you will add your settings)*:

```
// Utility function that contain Linkwise Affiliate script
function linkwise_affiliate_scripts( $order_id ){

    ## --- YOUR SETTINGS START BELOW --- ##

    $program_id  = '12686'; // <== Your program number
    $decimal_sep = ',';     // Decimal separator
    $currency    = '978';   // For "EUR" => See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

    ## --- END SETTINGS --- ##

    $order        = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_status = $order->get_status();
    $items_string = array();
    $count        = 0;

    ?>
    <script async src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/tl.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.lw=window.lw||function(){(lw.q=lw.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    lw .l=+new Date;
    lw("setProgram", "<?php echo $program_id; ?>");
    lw("setDecimal", "<?php echo $decimal_sep; ?>");
    </script>
    <script>

        lw("setCurrency", "<?php echo $currency; ?>"); // Set your currency
        <?php
            foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ):
                $count++;
                $item_id        = $item->get_id(); // The item ID

                // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
                $product        = $item->get_product();
                $product_id     = $item->get_product_id(); // Product ID
                $price_excl_vat = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); // Unit price excluding VAT
                $item_qty       = $item->get_quantity(); // Item quantity
                $payout         = '1'; // (???)

                // The string for the <noscript> at the bottom
                $items_string[] = "itemid[$count]=$item_id&amp;itemprice[$count]=$price_excl_vat&amp;itemquantity[$count]=$item_qty&a
        mp;itempayout[$count]=$payout";

        ?>
        lw("addItem", {
            id: "<?php echo $item_id; // Or can be the product ID (may be) ?>"
            ,price: "<?php echo $price_excl_vat; ?>"
            ,quantity: "<?php echo $item_qty; ?>"
            ,payout: "<?php echo $payout; ?>"
        });
        <?php
            endforeach;

            // Set the array of items strings in a unique string
            $items_string = implode( '&amp;', $items_string );
        ?>
        // Other items types
        <?php
            $coupon_discounts = $coupon_discounts_tax = 0;
            foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $item_coupon ){
                $coupon_discounts     += $item_coupon->get_discount();
                $coupon_discounts_tax += $item_coupon->get_discount_tax();
            }
        ?>
        lw("setCoupon", "<?php echo $coupon_discounts; ?>");
        lw("thankyou", {
            orderid: "<?php echo $order_id; ?>"
            ,status: "<?php echo $order_status; ?>"
        });
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <img
        src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/acl.php?program=<?php echo $program_id; ?>&amp;decimal=<?php echo $decimal_sep; ?>&amp;<?php echo $items_string; ?>&amp;coupon_price=<?php echo $coupon_discounts; ?>&amp;status=<?php echo $order_status; ?>&amp;orderid=<?php echo $order_id; ?>" style="width:0px;height:0px;"/>
    </noscript>
    <?php echo 'test';
}
```

And the hooked function that will run the utility function *(with 2 different possibilities)*:

A) Using `woocommerce_thankyou` action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou','wc_linkwise_affiliate_thanyou_integration', 20, 1 );
function wc_linkwise_affiliate_thanyou_integration( $order_id ){
    if ( empty($order_id) || $order_id == 0 )
        return; // Exit

    linkwise_affiliate_scripts( $order_id ); // Run the Linkwise Affiliate
}
```

B) or Using WordPress `wp_footer` action hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wc_linkwise_affiliate_order_received_integration' );
function wc_linkwise_affiliate_order_received_integration() {
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) )
        return; // Exit

    global $wp;

    $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
    if ( empty($order_id) || $order_id == 0 )
        return; // Exit

    linkwise_affiliate_scripts( $order_id ); // Run the Linkwise Affiliate
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.

You can check in your browser console, you will see no errors and the correct output flags in Order received page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i want to apologize for not including the following code: <script async src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/tl.js"></script> <script> window.lw=window.lw||function(){(lw.q=lw.q||[]).push(arguments)};lw .l=+new Date; lw("setProgram", "program ID as given by Linkwise"); lw("setDecimal", "decimal separator i.e. , or ."); </script> they did provide for the header of every page since it was easy to implement. Maybe this is one for the missing lw(). What are my next step? Do i need to include the master Script? How and where since i am not experienced.

Comment: I am just thinking that the missing JavaScript (js) file must be int this source src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/tl.js which load on every page on the header. I just added the suggested code in the end of my child theme php file and the thank you page does not load anymore.

Comment: Great Solution my friend. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: @TasosKaratzoglou Just for info: I have maid an update with 2 alternatives (2 different working hooks)… You can keep your version as it works…