# Tracking and Retargeting Technical Integration Guide

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

Tracking and Retargeting
Technical Integration
Guide Linkwise

I need some help  configuring and add the codes to my Woocomerce store

- I have already see carefully the thread
  [Linkwise Affiliate integration in Woocommerce thankyou page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944371/linkwise-affiliate-integration-in-woocommerce-thankyou-page#)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9VCM.png)

Linkwise add some codes for retargeting and it will be very usefull if you help me fill the corect variables

```
3. Retargeting tracking codes

Product listing 



    <script>
    lw("addItem", {
     id: "ID (as given in the XML) of first product shown"
     ,price: "unit price of first product, without VAT e.g. 13,49"
    });
    lw("addItem", {
     id: "ID (as given in the XML) of second product shown"
     ,price: "unit price of second product, without VAT e.g. 25,16"
    });
    // more items
    lw("listItems");
    </script>
```

3.4 Product page

```
<script>
lw("addItem", {
 id: "ID (as given in the XML) of product"
 ,price: "unit price of product, without VAT e.g. 13,49"
});
lw("viewItem");
</script>
```

3.5 Shopping cart/basket

```
<script>
lw("addItem", {
 id: "ID (as given in the XML) of first product shown"
 ,price: "unit price of first product, without VAT e.g. 13,49"
 ,quantity: "quantity of first product"
});
lw("addItem", {
 id: "ID (as given in the XML) of second product shown"
 ,price: "unit price of second product, without VAT e.g. 25,16"
 ,quantity: "quantity of second product"
});
// more items
lw("viewCart");
</script>
```